Calculate $\int_C \frac{z^3 \, dz}{2z^4+1}$, $C$ is the circle $|z|=1$

Calculate $\int_C \frac{z^3 \, dz}{2z^4+1}$, $C$ is the circle $|z|=1$ using Cauchy's Residue Theorem

I think I know what to do this procedurally, but I'm observing that my calculation of this is becoming incredibly messy. I was hoping somebody could point out a less messy way to do this (if such a way exists) - or if I should continue the painstaking process listed below:

Now, $2z^4+1 = 2(z^4+\frac{1}{2})$. Let $u=z^2$. Then we solve $u^2+\frac{1}{2} = 0$. So
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
u^2 = - \frac{1}{2} \implies u = \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i \implies z  = \pm \sqrt{\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i}     
    \end{split}
\end{align}
Now, as $\left| \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} \right| < 1$, all of these poles are simple and have length less than $1$ and hence are interior to the our curve. We start by finding the residue for $z= \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i}$:
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \mathrm{Res}_{z=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i}} f(z) &= \lim_{z \to \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i}}\left(z-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i\right)  \cdot  \frac{z^3}{2z^4+1} \\
        &= \lim_{z \to \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i}} \frac{z^3}{2\left(z- -\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i}\right)\left(z- \sqrt{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i}\right)\left(z- -\sqrt{\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}i}\right)}
    \end{split}
\end{align}

Now, assuming I haven't made any grave calculation errors here, is there a simpler method to continuing this calculation that doesn't involve direct calculation of the limit? As one would note, this is becoming incredibly cumbersome for such an elementary graduate level problem

Use l'Hôpital's rule for the limits.

Hint: use Argument Principle(Avoid computing four residues):
$$\int_C \frac{z^3}{2z^4+1} \, dz
=\frac18\int_C \frac{(2z^4+1)'}{2z^4+1}\, dz
=\frac{2\pi i}8\cdot[N(f,C)-P(f,C)]
=\frac{\pi i}4\cdot(4-0)=\pi i,$$
where $N(f,C)$ is the number of zeros of $f(z)=2z^4+1$ contained in $C$ and $P(f,C)$ is the number of poles of $f(z)=2z^4+1$ contained in $C$.

This method is great because it's straightforward and utilizes a fundamental result. Thanks!

Using residue theorem,
$$\oint_{\mathcal C}\frac{z^3\,\mathrm dz}{2z^4+1}=2\pi i\sum_{z_i\in\text{Int}\,\mathcal C}\text{Res}\left(\frac{z^3}{2z^4+1}, z_i\right)$$
The integrand has $4$ singular $1$st order poles, all of them inside $\mathcal C:|z|=1$:
$$2z^4+1=0\iff z^4=-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}e^{i(2k+1)\pi}\iff z=\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{2}}e^{i(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{4}},\ \ k\in\mathbf Z$$
Then
$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{z^3}{2z^4+1}, z_i\right)=\lim_{z\to z_i}\left[(z-z_i)\frac{z^3}{2z^4+1}\right]=\lim_{z\to z_i}z^3\underbrace{\lim_{z\to z_i}\frac{z-z_i}{2z^4+1}}_{\frac{0}{0}\implies\text{L'Hôpital}}=z_i^3\cdot\frac{1}{8z^3_i}=\frac{1}{8}$$
Since we said there are $4$ singularities,
$$\oint_{\mathcal C}\frac{z^3\,\mathrm dz}{2z^4+1}=2\pi i\sum_{i=1}^4\frac{1}{8}=i\pi$$

This reminds of Dan's answer because it reveals to us the fact that all four residues calculated will be equal. Thanks for your response.

Yet an "other" approach, that takes the last limit from the question, and tries to do something with it "explicitly".
Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ be the roots of $2z^4+1=0$. Then if $a$ is one of them, the others are $ia$, $-a$, and $-ia$. The limit $L(a)$ under question is mot-a-mot:
$$
\begin{aligned}
L(a) &=\lim_{z\to a}\frac {z^3}{2(z-(ia))(z-(-a))(z-(-ia))}
\text{ (plug in $z=a$))}
\\
&=\frac{a^3}{2\;a(1-i)\cdot a(1-(-1))\cdot a(1-(-i))}=\frac 1{2(1-i)(1+i)(1+1)}=\frac 18\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
All four roots are inside the contour $C$, so the integral is $2\pi i \cdot 4\cdot\frac 18=\pi i$.

This method is so fascinating. I like that you were able to express each singularity in terms of merely one of them; this is certainly a method for finding residues that is most useful when the singularities share some symmetry about the origin and axes, as is the case here.
